# To open app chooser dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make a share button for Japanese application. On this share button, i want to give the user to  be able to open any application viz. whatsapp, Line, Hetache, fb, tweeter and any sharing app that is in the users device. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `Intent.ACTION_SEND` for it.

Comment: Please do not give solution for https://github.com/tttzof351/social-sharing-dialogs as these are limited to certain networks only. I want to open any app. Please suggest a solution. @PiyushGupta and NAP

Comment: It will show the app in your dialog if it is already installed in your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this with

> android.support.v7.app

library,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ShareActionProvider actionProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);  
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ActionBarCompat is Awesome! Support Lib v7 #Xamarin");
    actionProvider.setShareIntent (intent);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_edit:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Editing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Sharing Intent! Why did I forget?.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use send action with implicit intent and allow to choose sharing apps from device.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Also check for more option : http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html